# SAP Portal vs an ASP.NET Portal ... proof of concept?

Tags: asp.net, sap-basis

We have an SAP portal, which is not user friendly from clients point of view, we as ASP.NET developers suggest to use ASP.NET as a presentation layer for SAP backend system instead of SAP portal.
We already integrated successfully to SAP backend for data insert and retrieval.

So, we need to show ASP.NET power to SAP Team! How an ASP.NET portal will be much better than SAP portal.
We though of AJAX functionality, look & feel of UI, and application mobility (cross browser).

So, what are the pros and cons of an ASP.NET portal compared to SAP portal? What are the issues SAP portal has, ASP.NET doesn't?
Briefly, how to convince decision makers of ASP.NET over SAP from UI/Performance points of view?

Comment: If you think that ASP.NET is better that SAP Portal then you must have your reasons, if those aren't enough to convince the SAP team then you may not have sound reasons and need to review your understanding. Regardless, this question is subjective.

Comment: @Lazarus: I'm not looking for endless conversation here as a subjective question, I'm looking for power points of an ASP.NET portal against SAP portal. I don't know more about SAP portals, so I need to get pros and cons of both of them.

Comment: I'd suggest your SAP team are your first port of call, tell them about the great points of ASP.NET, get them to tell you the great points about SAP Portal (you'll learn in the process which makes it worth doing regardless). Where there are overlaps or things you've forgotten to include you can then discuss with them further. This kind of discussion is *always* subjective and you'll get as many opinions as there are answers, it's not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My five cents:

> 1. Nobody ever got fired for a SAP portal that didn't really work
> 2. On the other hand, if you have a portal you make yourself, the
>      potential to get fired when it doesn't
>      work is much higher, because you can't
>      blame SAP for everything.
> 3. SAP software never really works (corollary)
> 4. Consider point 3 on point 2 and the impact a failure of your portal will have on your carreer
> 5. Do you have the TIME to do that ? ( = != do you have the knowledge)
> 6. In case you are a Windows Forms developer, are you aware that it's much more difficult to make web UIs interactive (JavaScript compatibility + security issues) ?
> 7. Caution with AJAX. Ajax is great, and so is Google Chrome, but IE 8 & 9
>      aren't, and there also still is IE 6
> 8. Is it for internal use only ? If so, I strongly recommend Silverlight
>      over AJAX (see points 7, 6)
> 9. Do you sufficiently understand the SAP system ? What if SAP makes updates
>      that breakes your system ?
> 10. Data validation: SAP doesn't do it, the interface must do it, are you
>       capable of that (date formats &
>       internationalization, Unicode) ?
> 11. Have you really already integrated successfully a SAP backend for data
>       insertion and retrieval? Or did you
>       just talk about it? Was it in
>       productive use? Are you sure it works
>       ? SAP systems are highly complex
>       things, don't ever say you're quickly gonna do anything there.

Comment: For Have you really already integrated successfully a SAP backend for data insertion and retrieval? Yes, I've done using NCo "SAP .NET Connector", it is an official SAP connector for .NET.

Comment: I got from you answer that you don't recommend using ASP.NET, right?

Comment: @Ahmed: Wrong, there's nothing wrong with ASP.NET MVC. What I recommend is NOT using SAP Software AT ALL. And the other thing I don't recommend is trusting in IE's ability to properly execute AJAX, because it doesn't. You will be faster if you do it in ASP.NET (vs. SAP) though, but it's not risk-free. If you must, I recommend ASP.NET MVC + Silverlight.

Comment: +1 for not using SAP at all! However, AJAX works perfectly in IE. In fact its been there since IE5. MS created the XMLHTTPRequest as an ActiveX control that was later adopted by other browsers and built into browsers, and is now becoming a W3C specification. The trick is to use jQuery so that AJAX "just works", without thinking about browser specific issues.

Comment: I used JQuery, I'm not that naive. But I did a lot of page updates, and due to improper threading in  IE, the result was a bsod - always. It worked fine with Chrome and FireCrap.

Answer (score 2):

There is a product, Duet, that allows you to access SAP from a SharePoint frontend.

This gives you a friendly user interface while you still have your business processes in SAP.

See: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/duet-enterprise-for-sap-and-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to go to SCN ([SAP Community Network](http://scn.sap.com)) and ask this question on a forum dedicated to [SAP Portal solution](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/index.jspa#2). I am sure that you will get a lot of answers that might help you to make the decision.